# Extracting all the contents from webpage having similar xpath(contents that can be extracted in a list)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have to scrape this page, http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature.
While using xpath i could scrape the movie name, 'The Lost City of Z'. Here is the code:

```
  driver_t.get('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature')
  x= driver_t.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/h3/a')
  print x.text
```

In order to scrape all the movies, i removed [1] from the xpath

```
  driver_t.get('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature')
  x= driver_t.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/h3/a')
  print x.text
```

But, the output is only the first movie's name('The Lost City of Z')

This worked in 'R' but its not working in python(selenium webdriver). Could someone tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

In order to scrape all the movies from the page with url `http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature` instead of `find_element_by_xpath` we will be using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` which will return a list. Next we will iterate through the list and retrieve the text and print them one by one. Here is the code block for your reference:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature")
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a")
for title in titles:
    movie_name = title.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(movie_name)
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanx a lot!! :) This was what i wanted. Could you just tell me how did you get this xpath, "//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a"? And, what is the significance of Options functions.

Comment: Okay, in simple words, xpath, "//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a" identifies the common xpath of the elements of our interest. Options class is helping you to  "start-maximized", "disable the infobar" and "disable if any extension tries to load by default". Thanks

Comment: Could you suggest me a link where i can study this in detail? Finding the common xpath is becoming a bit tricky when i tried it for other website.

Answer (score 0):

You want `find_elements_by_xpath` (plural elements).

You can also simplify the xpath formula to:

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]//a')
```

Then the first and last titles become available as:

```
>>> titles[0].text
'The Lost City of Z'
>>> titles[99].text
'Raw'
```

However, I notice that the full title of the last film is 'Raw II'. You might deem it necessary to use something like this as well, and then discard the year part.

```
>>> titles[99].find_element_by_xpath('../span[2]').text
'(II) (2016)'
```

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath helped!!:) Thank you.